# Is converting high voltage AC into high voltage DC possible for my application?

Tags: transformer, high-voltage

I want to convert 2,320 volts AC into 
1,000 volts DC. But I’m not sure if I can do this with my transformer KVA rating.

My power source is a 20 amp 120 - 125 volt outlet. With testiing the outlet with a ammeter on the AC volt setting it says 122 or 123 volts.

Here are the details of the AC transformer I want to use.

Note: The following values are based in experimental data and testing. Besides the KVA. KVA is done with a calculator.

Volts Input: 120-125

Watts Input: 2,400-2,500

Amps Input: 19-20

Running Frequency: 60 Hz

KVA Rating Of Transformer: 2.28

————————————————————————————

Volts Output: 2,320

Watts Output: 1,392

Amps Output: 0.6

Running Frequency: 60 Hz

Use: I plan on using this for an electromagnet and powering multiple resistive electromagnets to propel a projectile.

More Info: I want to make a high intensity electromagnetic flux centered around a pvc pipe by using magnet wire. I am currently still calculating the wire gauge for the magnet wire.

Problem: I need to know if this can be done? If this can’t be done what should I do instead?

P.S I’m still editing this accordingly to the responses I got from users.

Comment: Sure, this kind of thing happens all the time for electrified railways.  Especially with older systems where the railway itself is DC - they used to use motor generator sets, today they probably use IGBTs.  But like most everything you've posted since joining this site, this question is problematic.

Comment: Do you need a well regulated 1,000 VDC? There are IGBT modules rated to 3,700 VDC. If not much current is needed you could just build a linear power supply.

Comment: yep, so for example you say you want to convert 2.32 kV AC to 1 kV DC. That's complicated enough. But then, out of thin air, you seem to be mentioning a AC transformer, which seems to bear exactly no relationship to the question aside from you saying it has an output voltage (under which circumstances?!) of 2.32 kV. And that in that transformer, you have a magic disappearance of more than 1 kW of power, which I **really** hope is not the case. Really, explain what you have, and what you're trying to solve, with way, way more of "the big picture". This question simply makes too little sense!

Comment: I need a well regulated 1,000 VDC.

Comment: you added "which I will use as a power source"; that was obvious, but for what? Bigger picture, please!

Comment: *Regulation* is a broad term that includes voltage specifications, responses to load variations, responses to changes in the power supply input side, etc. The term "well regulated" is not a specification. It's a conclusion based upon detailed knowledge of the power supply ***and*** the needs of the system that uses it. It would therefore help if (a) you write detailed specifications leaving us blind to end use but with good details regardless; or else, (b) specify details about the end use of it so that we can infer them.

Comment: With your edit, it makes even less sense: You cannot control voltage and amperage simultaneously; that's not how electricity works! You set a voltage, and the load defines the current that flows, or you supply a current and the voltage is the potential difference across the load – you can't do both. How would you do a "1000 V 1 A" setting when you just leave the source unconnected (open)? Where is that 1A going to flow? How would you set that 1000V 1A with a short? Where will that voltage be measurable?

Comment: I'm voting to close as unclear because OP continuously fails to explain what they need in the bigger picture, leaving us unable to infer what they technically need, whilst simultaneously supplying physically self-contradicting specifications.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course it is possible.  This schematic section shows how my (ancient) oscilloscope makes 3.2kV DC out of 1200VAC.

[image]

The trick isn't in getting the high voltage.

The trick is getting the high voltage and the high current - without killing yourself in the process.

You will need high voltage diodes (readily available) that can also handle the required current (also readily available.)

A couple or three 1N4007 in series will handle the voltage and the current.   Or use a more modern equivalent, easily found on the web site of your favorite distributor, with a reverse voltage rating at least twice the desired output voltage and a sufficient current rating.

The hard part will be the capacitor.

Look up how to calculate the filter capacitor for a half wave rectifier, given the frequency, the expected load (current,)  and the allowed ripple (how much variation the output voltage is allowed.)

The hard part (or maybe just expensive part) will be getting a capacitor with enough capacitance with a high enough voltage rating.

The last time I built a replacement high voltage section for my old oscilloscope, I had to use 4 very large film capacitors in a series/parallel combination to get the needed capacitance and voltage rating.

Yours will be **much** larger.

You will also need to watch out for clearance around the leads.  At such voltages, an air gap can become a conductor when a piece of dust floats through.

---

You scare me considerably.  You blithely talk of high voltages and high currents and then ask basic question like this one.

The power involved is bad enough, but you are building this for continuous operation.  That means **loads** of energy to kill yourself with.

Even a momentary spark at that power level can cause considerable damage - to your gadgets or **you.**

---

[This site gives the equations for calculating the apprpriate values for the smoothing capacitor.](https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/analogue_circuits/power-supply-electronics/capacitor-smoothing-circuits.php)  A quick run at a calculator delivers truly scary capacitor values.

Comment: The reason why i do talk about high voltages as as piece of cake is because I have experience with high voltage. Around 25 kV - 100kV AC.

Comment: Thanks for giving me a better perspective on my question. I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @ScientistSmithYT so, with that experience why do you need to ask the question - should be easy for you right??

Comment: @Solar Mike I am experienced with high voltages not detailed circuit schematics.

Answer (score 2):

First problem in your question, you have a choice to make ....you CANNOT regulate BOTH voltage and current. You must choose one or the other to regulate. You can of course regulate voltage and limit current (which is quite different).

Given your information. 2320V AC when rectified will give you a peak voltage of 3248V. To then try and produce a 1000V DC regulated supply would be shear madness.

If you are stuck with the transformer simply because that's what you have, then get an autotransformer for the input. Crank the input voltage down to approximately 40V AC and you will produce 1000VDC when rectified. 
Depending on the capabilities of the transformer and the autotransformer, output power in the kW/kVA range should be possible.  Autotransformers are cheap.
Here's a [2kVA](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B071X9X7FH) for just $120:
[image]

If you need moderately well regulated 1kV then you could use a motorized autotransformer (more expensive of course). If you need regulation beyond that then you could build a regulator at those voltages (probably linear) that would drop only 50-60V.The challenge is to provide high voltage capacitive filtering to get the ripple down.

A much better way to produce kW levels at 1000VDC is to use an SMPS solution. Better regulation, smaller capacitors, lower power losses.

Comment: 40VAC, or 400VAC?

Comment: @JRE. The OP clearly states the transformer is 120 - 2320 VAC. To reduce the ouptut voltage of the transformer you need to reduce the input voltage, hence setting the autotransformer to to 40V AC output will produce about 773 VAC out of the transformer. Rectify this 773VAC and you get about 1kV peak DC. Do you need a diagram?

Comment: Had a brainfart.  I was thinking "voltage out of the HV transformer."  A voltage doubling rectifier given 400VAC would also deliver (around) 1000VDC.